# Webhook doesn't sent body, Shopify

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I suscribe some events webhook in Shopify.

shopify template use this function

```
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path, // path to webhook
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers }) //<- this
);
```

But i received this error.

```
Failed to process webhook: Error: No body was received when processing webhook testing a webhook`
```

so the subscription works but well, it is having body but for a reason the library can process it. I already try to parse the body in Json inclusive to text without success

I need to process webhooks using express template in shopify. I can make my own implementation, but it would be taken so much time

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figure out what is the problem [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/guides/webhooks.md)

So only need to write `express.text({type: '*/*'})`  before `shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })`. That is because the library processes that as a "rawbody". after that you can use express.json() to process other request normally

Comment: I am still receiving the same error even though I added the middle you mentioned here. is there anything else I maybe missing?

Comment: well, i made a little change to my code but the logic is the same `shopify.config.webhooks.path, express.text({ type: '*/*' }), shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })`